# Teradata SQL - Convert values separated by ; in a single column to multiple rows

Tags: teradata

I have a single column with comma separated values like below.

sel job_dependency from test_table;

### job_dependency

1;2;3;4;5;6

I need to convert it into below format in Teradata SQL where each number is a row.

### job_dependency

1
2
3
4
5
6

Any help would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There's a table function for this task:

```
WITH cte AS 
 (
   SELECT
      1 AS inKey -- might be a column, either INT or VarChar up to 60 bytes
                 -- Other data types should be CASTed to VarChar (and back in the Select)
     ,job_dependency2 AS inString
   FROM test_table
 )
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
 ( StrTok_Split_To_Table(cte.inKey, cte.inString, ';')
   RETURNS (outKey INTEGER, -- data type must match input column
             tokenNum INTEGER,
             token VARCHAR(20))
 ) AS dt
```